# gob: type not registered for interface: fasthbbftv1.BroadcastMessage

Tags: go, rpc

My code organization structure is like this

```
package_name/
    server/
        rpc_server.go
    client_test.go
```

1. I register an RPC server to receive messages from other nodes.

```golang
type RPCMessageArgs struct {
    Operation string
    Info      Message
}

type Message struct {
    NodeID  uint64
    Payload interface{}
}

func init() {
    gob.Register(BroadcastMessage{})
}

func main() {
    // start rpc server
}
```

2. I start my RPC server in the server folder with the command `go run rpc_server.go`.
3. My test code in the client_test.go is as follows

```golang
package package_name

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "log"
    "net/rpc"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

type BroadcastMessage struct {
    Payload interface{}
}


func TestClient(t *testing.T) {
    gob.Register(BroadcastMessage{})
    args := &RPCMessageArgs{}
    args.Info.NodeID = 3
    args.Info.Payload = &BroadcastMessage{}
    reply := &RPCMessageReply{}
    client, err := rpc.Dial("tcp", ":800"+strconv.Itoa(1))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dialing: ", err)
    }
    err = client.Call("RPCServer.RemoteCall", args, reply)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("call error: ", err)
    }
}
```

4. I get this error

```
call error: gob: name not registered for interface: "package_name.BroadcastMessage"
```

Comment: I moved gob.Register call to `func init{}` in `rpc_server.go`. It still does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very low-level mistake. I defined two `type BroadcastMessage` in two files, one in `rpc_server.go` and one in `client_go.go`. I should define these structures in a package, and then let these two files call these structures.
After the change, my code structure is as follows：

```
package_name/
    args/
        rpc_args.go
    server/
        rpc_server.go
    client_test.go
```

Define the relevant structure in the rpc_args.go file, import the args package in other files, and then call the `gob.Register()` command in `rpc_server.go` and `client_test.go` to run normally.